# why doesn't my menu button stay in the right place when you change the size of the window?

Tags: html, css

I got my menu button to be in the right place when im in fullscreen but if the browser window change in size in any way the button moves, what am i doing wrong?
i have tried to align it using different "position"
Heres my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</head>

<body style="background-color: black">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DropDownMenu.css">
<div style="position:;" class="dropdown">
<button style="background: url(indexLiten.jpg)" class="dropbtn"></button>
</div>
<center><h1 class="h1" style="color: white; font-size: 50px" >Intro to Vortexcall</h1></center>
  <center><p>What is the Vortex?<br>
      </p></center>

    
</body>
```

and my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
.dropbtn {
position: absolute;
background-color: #562088;
color: whitesmoke;
left: 110px;
padding: 50px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;

}
```

Comment: Well, you put some content in the *center* and some *110px from the left of the window*. Why wouldn't they move relative to each other?

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is not enough ,I see that you have put absolute positioning, that means that the parent element should have a position relative, have you put a position:relative property to the parent element? And one other thing, you have placed padding, and left:110px, why should the button not move when the screen size is changing. It should move and adapt because of responsive design. It should always be 110px from the left of the relative positioned parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have linked to your style sheet inside the `<body>` tag!!! You need to do that in the `head` tag! That's why your css rules don't get applied!

Just a quick tip on your css, when you have just one element, it's a best practice to give it an `id` instead of a `class`.

For example if you have one single button, it's better to give it an `id` not a `class`.